# Is there a way to make set up reference transaction paypal's rest API

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to implement paypal using reference transactions, i read that NVP/SOAP API allows this creating a billing agreement and then reference this billing agreement ID for future payment requests.

I want to know if this is possible to achieve using the REST API.

I know that REST API allows to create billing plans and agreements for subscription plans, but this is not what i need, i need to handle recurring payments on my own, where users can approve the agreement on Paypal when they susbscribe on my app and then charge them periodically with a cron to the approved account on PayPal.

Is this possible? if so can anyone provide an example of the flow i must follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with **no**.  What you want is Reference Transactions for the workflow your talking about.

Unfortunately, you can see in the base REST API bug tracker the following ticket [Reference Transactions #44](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/44) which is tagged with the nvp-soap-parity tag meaning we don't have it in REST yet.

When I look through the [REST API Reference for billing agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/), there's nothing that gives me hope that there's poorly publicized way to make it happen.  And lastly when you look at [PHP REST SDK Class Documentation, for the Plan class](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Plan.html), it looks like there is nothing supported outside of plans that have a defined frequency and amount.

The good news is you can still use the merchant-sdk-php for now, even though NVP is apparently deprecated from Jan 1, 2017 forward. and then just plan to change things over to REST when the Reference Transactions bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Load the [REST API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) and scroll down to the Billing Plans and Agreements section.  You'll find chapters for "Create an agreement", "Execute an agreement", etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As i understand agreements require a Plan definition, also it would be Paypal itself who would manage recurring billing, what i need is to manage recurring billing on my own, i mean i want to request the next payment with my own cron using the agreement reference, this is not documented on paypal manuals and seems to be available only for NVP/SOAP API.

Comment: Yes, reference transactions and recurring billing are separate things.  When PayPal manages it that's recurring billing.  Reference transactions would leave it up to you, and according to the REST docs they support both separately.

Comment: But i cant seem to find reference transactions for rest api un the docs. So it seems that i would need to implementación SetExpressCheckout API.

Comment: I personally still prefer Express Checkout anyway, so yeah, that's probably what I would recommend.  This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make those calls very quick and easy for you.  PayPal's own integration team uses it quite a bit.  That said, if you click the link in my answer to view the REST API reference, and scroll down to the Billing Plans and Agreements section, you'll see that it mentions the separate methods and you can do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, Reference Transactions through REST are technically possible, but you have to get the feature approved by a paypal account manager. Paypal calls this "limited release".

Therefore, the feature is not included in the documentation which is officially linked, but in this "hidden" one: https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/reference-transactions/